# IOR in Blender Internal (raytraced)

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm confused about IOR in Blender Internal as used in raytraced transparency.
To demonstrate my issue, I set up a camera looking through a transparent sheet with IOR>1 (and slightly tinted) at a textured surface.
You can clearly see the expected refraction.

But when I flip normals, I get exactly the same render!
My question is therefore:  How does Blender Internal determine the "in/out"-side if it does not use the normals for that?

Placing the camera inside a properly closed transparent volume with IOR does not change anything.

Clearly, I can invert the IOR to treat camera rays, but I came across this issue when reflections going out and then back into the glass material misbehaved.

[image: Scene Setup]
[image: Refraction visible]

Comment: It doesn't use normals to determine where the ray is. It just swaps a traversal flag on ray pass.

Comment: I think this is the answer, result looks fine to me now, thank you!

Comment: @user2859 Feel free to add that as a proper answer

Answer (score 1):

From [user2859's comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9188/ior-in-blender-internal-raytraced#comment14985_9188):

> It doesn't use normals to determine where the ray is. It just swaps a traversal flag on ray pass.